# Выборка за датой

Tags: sqlite, sql, mysql

**Выборка через** ***SQLite***.
Есть такие записи:

```
id  |  dateAdd  
1   |  03-04-2014  
2   |  05-06-2014  
3   |  09-09-2014
```

**Как сделать выборку по дате?** к примеру только те, которые с датой больше.

```
SELECT * FROM r WHERE date(dateAdd) >= date('05-06-2014')
```

> ни так >= 
> ни так < 
> ни так = 
> и т.д

**Результата не дает**, вообще ничего нету, ни ошибок не результата.

Comment: .

    SELECT * FROM r WHERE dateAdd >= '05-06-2014';

у меня такой запрос вернул все, что должен был

Comment: @Fike, это данные в алфавитном порядке а dateAdd просто строковый тип. добавьте в список, например, 19 февраля 2000 года, то есть "19-02-2000". тоже попадет в вашу выборку.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, не знал, мой факап

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select date('2014-02-01'), date('01-02-20014');

> 2014-02-01 | null

У вас неверный формат даты. формат должен быть Y-m-d.

Comment: А если в Android-Приложении дата записана DD-MM-YYYY, можно как-то изменить дату при роботе в БД? ну я так полагаю, придется, делать ф-ю которая будет делать реверс даты?

Comment: @Юра Сучко, в SQLite нет типа даты, но вы можете хранить дату в трех видах:

* Строкой в виде YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
* REAL количество дней по юлианскому календарю как количество дней от 4к до н.э.
* INTEGER как unixtime

дальше с этими значениями может уже работать функция date и strftime. Вашу дату лучше сейчас переделать на верный формат, а еще лучше хранить в unix time'е.  


Про "реверс даты" забудьте.